# Plotting 1M+ intensity reading as custom shapes with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, clustering, markers, mongodb

I currently have a database (Mongo, atm) holding roughly 1M points of data corresponding lat/lon/intensity values that I'd like to plot over a region using the Google Maps API.

Ideally, I'd like to have full control over the representation of the points, as the intent is to allow the end-user to control color/opacity/shape through a series of controls. I also need the ability to specify a color range which maps back to the intensity of a given point.

That said, I've investigated using Google Fusion Tables, but for a heavily customized app I found that display styles limiting. I've also looked a bit into marker clustering, as well as a number of external plugins, but none seem to provide the option to generate the marker type dynamically.

Any help/advice/direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To show that many points on the map, you should look at using a map server. I don't know anything about Mongo but a quick Google search shows that there is a [GeoServer plugin for Mongo](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/GeoServer-Plugin-for-MongoDB-td6277558.html). The client-side [Google Maps Clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) will probably struggle with that many points

Comment: Is seeing the actual points required, or does using something like a heat map work? For that many points, you definitely need some sort of server-side solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use OpenLayers which allows strategy based rendering. You actually need to limit no of points rendered in different zoom level. see this [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html) for better understanding

Hope that helps